# Set the max height for a multi line text box in a view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, view, multiline-text-field

How do I set a max height for a multi-line text box in a view?

Many columns squeezes the content in the multi-line text box making the whole list overly long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the CSS modification or item height modification using JavaScript, you can pinpoint it to the actual item and not to all items with same CSS class throughout the Site Collection.

Either add Script Editor Web Part (or CEWP) to page and add the required script there, or include it in your .master page and perhaps limit the scope by only modifying the height when window.location.href (= page URL) matches some specific condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the CSS class. Then you can set the `height` attribute to your desired value. Keep in mind that this will change it everywhere.